# Que tipo de datos devuelve una funcion next en express y typescript?

Tags: nodejs, typescript, express

Que tipo de datos devuelve la funcion next?. Si quito el void de la respuesta (Response | void) el tipo de dato me da error, por el next()
Pero tampoco puedo poner return next()

```
public async verifyUser(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<Response | void> {
    try {
// realiza la funcion
      next();
    } catch (e) {
      return HttpHandler.response(res, 500, { message: e.message });
    }
  }
```

Esta es la clase HttpHandler

```
import { Response } from 'express';

class HttpHandler {
  /**
   *
   * @param res
   * @param status
   * @param message
   * @param data
   * @returns
   */

  public response(res: Response, status: number, data = {}): Response {
    return res.status(status).json({ result: data });
  }
}
export default new HttpHandler();
```

El error es: *Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.ts(2366)*

Answer (score 0):

En teoría no tendrías por qué retornar. En  una petición exitosa se invoca al `next()` y en el catch de la excepción podrías quitar el return usando

```
     res.status(500).json({mensaje:e.message})
```

(ya no me acuerdo si esa sintaxis está bien, pero creo que es irrelevante ahora)

o bien dejar que el ErrorHandler lo tome y maneje aguas abajo

```
     next(e);
```

(si tienes un logger de errores esta es la manera de no llenar de `logger.info` la aplicación )

De todos modos, **el retorno de esa función nunca se usa**. Lo que sea que ocurra dentro, para empezar, será en un callback.

Si quieres retornar para cortar el flujo puedes usar un return vacío. De esa manera la funcionalidad queda intacta y tu salida (que insisto, no se usa) es homogénea.

---

Mirando los tipos de Express veo que lo correcto sería tipear tu método como un [RequestHandler](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/92e71182200ccc612feb6d4fd4c34ca9b9050c2c/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L58-L71)

```
export interface RequestHandler<
    P = ParamsDictionary,
    ResBody = any,
    ReqBody = any,
    ReqQuery = ParsedQs,
    Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>
> {
    (
        req: Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals>,
        res: Response<ResBody, Locals>,
        next: NextFunction,
    ): void;
}
```

Puedes entonces omitir los tipos en el método y declararlos en una interfaz:

```
import {RequestHandler} from 'express' 

interface IRoutingComponent {
  verifyUser: RequestHandler
}
```

Y a tu clase le pones el método sin tipos.

```
class RoutingComponent implements IRoutingComponent {

  public async verifyUser(req, res, next) {
    try {
      next();
    } catch (e) {
      return HttpHandler.response(res, 500, { message: e.message });
    }
  }
}
```